# MySQL Trigger Insert into same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table

```
tblTable1 (id, imei, type, value, commandid, state)
```

and second table which is copy of first table

```
tblTable2 (id, imei, type, value, commandid, state)
```

After updating state in `tblTable1`, I need insert into same tblTable1 new one record from `tblTable2` where `imei` is same. I create a `after update` trigger in `tblTable1` but I got a message that I can´t insert new record into table where trigger was called from.

Is another way to do this function?

---

EDIT : the trigger code (from comments) :

```
BEGIN 
    IF ((NEW.TYPE=53) and (NEW.STATE=1)) THEN CALL ADDCURRENTCONFIG(NEW.IMEI); 
    ELSEIF ((NEW.TYPE=53) and (NEW.STATE=3)) THEN 
        DELETE FROM tblBEFOREUNITNEWCONFIG WHERE IMEI=NEW.IMEI; 
    END IF; 
END
//
```

`ADDCURRENTCONFIG` is StoredProcedure which select record from `tblTable2` and insert him into `tblTable2`

Comment: Provide us the trigger you tried

Comment: BEGIN
  IF ((NEW.TYPE=53) and (NEW.STATE=1)) THEN
     CALL `ADDCURRENTCONFIG`(NEW.IMEI);
  ELSEIF ((NEW.TYPE=53) and (NEW.STATE=3)) THEN
     DELETE FROM `tblTable2` WHERE IMEI=NEW.IMEI; 
  END IF;
END
//ADDCURRENTCONFIG is StoredProcedure which select record from tblTable2 and insert him into tblTable2

Comment: Please show a whole trigger code, together with it's header `CREATE TRIGGER .........`, not only the trigger body within `BEGIN ... END` keywords.

Comment: DROP TRIGGER `tblUNITNEWCONFIG_after_upd_tr1`;
CREATE DEFINER = 'configuser'@'localhost' TRIGGER `tblUNITNEWCONFIG_after_upd_tr1` AFTER UPDATE ON `tblTable1`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF ((NEW.TYPE=53) and (NEW.STATE=1)) THEN
     CALL `ADDCURRENTCONFIG`(NEW.IMEI);
  ELSEIF ((NEW.TYPE=53) and (NEW.STATE=3)) THEN
     DELETE FROM `tblTable2` WHERE IMEI=NEW.IMEI; 
  END IF;
END;